# How do I convert a double to a proprietary floating point format in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a 20 bit proprietary floating point format defined as:

```
Bits: 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00
Use:   s  e  e  e  e  e  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m  m 

Where 
s = sign, (1=negative, 0=positive)
e = exponent, (10^0 to 10^31)
m = mantissa, (2^0 to 2^14-1, 0 to 16383)
```

This bit allocation gives a range of values from -16383 X 10^31 to +16383 X 10^31.

Now if I have a double value (or preferable decimal) in C#, how do I convert this number to this proprietary floating point format? There is a decimal constructor - `Decimal(int lo, int mid, int hi, bool isNegative, byte scale)` - that can help me to convert this format to a decimal but not the other way round. Over to you...

Comment: The opposite of that constructor is `decimal.GetBits(value)` - however, I'm not sure that will help you get a mantissa/exponent etc; simply: `decimal` *doesn't work that way*

Comment: When I did a Motorola Fast Float to IEEE conversion I created a struct with both float and integer fields using explicit layout so they overlapped. Then just mask, shift and otherwise fiddle about with the sign, exponent and mantissa as needed. As Marc suggested, decimal probably isn't the place to start.

Comment: Point noted, decimal is not the place to start, it was just something I bumped into in the attempt to convert a number to this strange format.

Comment: @MarcGravell: actually, decimal does more or less work the same way as the proprietary format described above. Decimal only has a negative scale of 0-28 (where 28 means 10^-28),  and that is a decimal scale too. It should be easy to convert that to the format given.

Comment: Wait a second: there are no fractions in the format above? Only integers?

Comment: No decimals (as they are implied in the actual implementation, i.e. there is a scaling factor but that's outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Eureka moment: the "proprietary floating point format" is not a floating point format at all, its a "scaled" integer format which should be pretty easy to encode. Will post a solution when I have one.

Comment: You mean the part where the exponent applies to a base of 10, rather than 2, just caught your eye?

Comment: Yes, got so caught up in the spec calling this a floating point number I did not see the wood for the trees!

Comment: What are the rules on normalization for the proprietary format?

Comment: What are the rounding rules? Consider converting 20,005. It is too big for the mantissa, so it will have to be rounded to 2000e1 or 2001e1.

Comment: Rule is to rounded up to the nearest integer.

Comment: How about the tie-breaker? For the example I gave, the two alternatives both differ from the exact value by 5, so neither is nearer than the other.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: The phrase "rounded up to the nearest integer" typically means ties go to either the next larger value or next higher value (it's somewhat ambiguous), but there's also an interesting corner case at 163865, which is exactly halfway between 163900 and 163830.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do the conversion, (probably not optimal):

```
public static class Converter
{
    private const int cSignBit = 0x80000; // 1 bit
    private const int cExponentBits = 0x7C000; // 5 bits
    private const int cMaxExponent = 0x1F; // 5 bits
    private const int cMantissaBits = 0x03FFF; // 14 bits
    private const double cExponentBase = 10;
    private const int cScale = 100000;

    public static int DoubleToAmount(double aValue)
    {
        // Get the sign
        bool lNegative = (aValue < 0);

        // Get the absolute value with scaling
        double lValue = Math.Abs(aValue) * cScale;

        // Now keep dividing by 10 to get the exponent value
        int lExponent = 0;
        while (Math.Ceiling(lValue) > cMantissaBits)
        {
            lExponent++;
            if (lExponent > cMaxExponent)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot convert amount", (Exception)null);
            lValue = lValue / (double)cExponentBase;
        }

        // The result that is left rounded up is the mantissa
        int lMantissa = (int)Math.Ceiling(lValue);

        // Now we pack it into the specified format
        int lAmount = (lNegative ? cSignBit : 0) + lExponent * (cMantissaBits + 1) + lMantissa;

        // And return the result
        return lAmount;
    }
}
```